# I am getting Microsoft jscript runtime error when initialising it on command prompt

Tags: javascript, node.js

[image]

Being new here i am not allowed to attach image. So here the link to the image for more clarity to my problem.

Script code:

```
var http = require('http');
var dt = require('./myfirstmodule');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/html'
    });
    res.write("The date and time is currently: " + dt.myDateTime());
    res.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: So what is in the script....

Comment: i did not understand what are you asking? script? are saying code?

Comment: Yes code. what you have in `myfirst.js` file

Comment: i can't paste my code here properly.

Comment: Hi Md - if you put four spaces before each line, your code should format properly.

Comment: @MdMozammil Edit your post, post the code, and click the code button to indent it.... Without the code, it is really hard to help you.

Comment: Someone did also i got -1 upvote on question.This forum is pretty active and amazing.Thanks

Comment: There is no problem with your code, initial it'll ask you for permission in to launch server just provide then it'll run

Comment: @kgangadhar  Where will i allow for permission in to launch.I am not getting anything.

Comment: The error dialog shown in your screenshot is very odd. Do you have a `node.js` file in your XHTML folder? It's running under WSH, not Node...

Answer (score 0):

As i mentioned earlier there is no issue with your code. When executing application created using `http server` for the first time for the Windows platform, you will get the form dialog shown in below Figure. It’s better to check **Private Network** and then click **Allow access**

In case of failure of Confirming from Windows Firewall to open a port, You will get above error.

[image]

Comment: Thanks everyone for responding to my problem. The port 8080 was using by oracle database that's why i was getting multiple problems.After changing the port from 8080 to 3010(or something) of oracle. I was asked to allow access to private network(@ kgangadhar mentioned,thanks again). Then it finally woked fine.